# URL Rewrite to hide subdirectory when accessing a specific page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to use my `.htaccess` to rewrite 
`http://example.com/subdirectory/page.php`
to only show up as `http://www.example.com/` or a variation that excludes the subfolder and only has `page.php`. I need it to work only for that specific page when it is accessed 
sadly I'm having trouble doing so considering I've never done it before!
Currently the rewrite looks like this.

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/subdir\/page\.php" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/subdir\/page\.php" [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^subdir/page.php(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Am I overcomplicating this or missing something important?

Comment: Could you explain better your desired behaviour? What you want is:  http://example.com/subdirectory/page.php to show content from http://example.com/page.php ?

Comment: I figured out a workaround, because I'm working with PHPBB I was able to move the page to the root and gain the same result. so now it's www.sitename.com/page.php like I wanted, I needed to set the DirectoryIndex to the page.php in htaccess to obtain that result.